# Linq to return true or false if a set contains distinct values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, ternary-operator

If the set I am returning contains only one distinct value, I would like to return that value (string). Otherwise, I would like to return "Multiple".

I have set this up as a ternary operator and would like to know if I can use Linq to SQL to determine whether or not the set contains a distinct value or multiple different values.

Something like the following:

```
Name = h.NameListings.Select(a=>a.NameId).CheckForDistinct() ? h.NameListings.Select(a=>a.NameId).First() : "Multiple"
```

I realize that CheckForDistinct() is not a Linq method; just using it to explain the behavior I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Name=h.NameListings.Select(a=>a.NameId).Distinct().Count()==1 ?
  h.NameListings.Select(a=>a.NameId).First():
  "Multiple";
```

Here's another one trip to the database solution, by catching an exception if there is more than one (May only work in English versions -- I don't know if exception messages can be translated).

```
string result="";
try {
  result=h.NameListings.Select(a=>a.NameId).Distinct().Single();
}
catch(InvalidOperationException ex) {
  if (ex.Message.Contains("more than one"))
    result="Multiple";
  else
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Ah, great. Very intuitive. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just want to throw in my 2cents and show an example of a solution with one trip to the database (and "one" line, haha):

```
var Name = h.NameListings
  .Select(a=>a.NameId)
  .Distinct()
  .ToArray()
  .Select( (name,index) => index == 0 ? name : "Multiple" )
  .LastOrDefault();
```

I am still using the ternary operator, but because you are looking for a Linq to SQL solution, the Select extension method with the index is not available. I assume that the different database providers have different mechanisms to get the row number of a query. That is why we need to add `ToArray()` to be able to materialize the query and use (the in-memory) Linq to Objects.

Apart from that, to explain my answer, all but the first entry gets a `"Multiple"`. If we really have more than one (distinct) `NameId` the we can be sure that the last entry will have `"Multiple"` in it, else it is either `null` or `NameId`.

In the end you might argue that my solution is less readable than Roberts, which I might agree with!